# Merging multiple huge .accdb files into one

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, ms-access

Could anyone guide me as to how to merge huge Access files (.accdb) files into one Access file. These files are pretty huge. Is there a way where I can split these files into smaller ones and then combine them? Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.
I found there is a software to do this but this is only for .mdb files.

Comment: What do you mean by huge? 1 gig? How many files? What is the relationship between the tables? How do the files relate to each other? Overlaps in records, different tables, the same tables? Is there any code or forms? The questions go on and on and how easy or hard it is to combine them depends on the answers.

Comment: The old Access limitation of 2GB still applies in 2007, if the files are that huge then you won't be able to merge them in to one, you may be better leaving them seperate and then linking the tables from each in to one front end accdb file

Comment: Each file is 2.5 gigs. 6 Files. No relation b/w the tables. Fields are the same for all files. Only records are different. I also have a.txt format of the files. Do you think it'll be easier to merge them using the .txt format. Please let me know if you need any more info. I'm a tad confused about this.@Remou

Comment: @MattDonnan Could you give me some tips on how to go about this or maybe a link. I know there is a lot available online, but coming from you would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: @user823911 This link should help you out (http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2007.php) but if Remou's answer is an option for you then I would recommend that instead : )

Answer (score 1):

If each file is 2.5 gigs, I reckon it is time to look at SQL Server Express. It is free, and the new version has a 10 gb limit ( http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx ). You will still be able to use MS Access as your front end. There are some fairly clear upgrade paths for MS Access to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Remou will try this out. Matt Donnan - Will try this method as well. Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't understand how the OP was able to stuff 2.5 GB into an ACCDB.  But if that's true, 6 of those at 2.5 GB each equals 15 GB, which exceeds SQL Server Express' capacity limit by 50%. If they were only 2 GB, we're still looking at 12 GB.

Comment: @HansUp I am betting on some overlap and some confusion.